# Confusion regarding statement of the Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: convex-analysis, banach-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I read about Hahn-Banach theorem from the book "Introduction to topology and modern analysis" by Simmons. There it was stated like this:

**Let $M$ be a linear subspace of a normed linear space $N$, and let $f$ be a functional defined on $M$. Then $f$ can be extended to a functional $f_0$ defined on the whole space $N$ such that $\|f_0\|$=$\|f\|$.**

But I also came across the following version of the theorem [See theorem 8, page 10](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02187)

**Let $S$ be a convex compact set in a finite dimensional Banach space. Let $ρ$ be a point in the space with $ρ \notin S$.Then there exists
a hyperplane that separates $ρ$ from $S$.**

I am unable to figure out the connection between the two statements. They seem unrelated to me and yet both of them have been stated as Hahn-Banach theorem. Can anyone please explain whether these two statements are equivalent? If they are then how do I obtain the latter from the former?

Explanations in simple language would be helpful as I am not a mathematics student.

Comment: You might want to read (or skim the relevant parts) of the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) article; it's pretty thorough (for a Wiki article, anyhow) and covers both versions of the theorem and how they connect.

Comment: This is a little glib, but I think the Minkowski functional of a set is the 'geometric' connection.

Comment: The Hahn-Banach theorem that might enlighten the connection states that if $g:C \to \mathbf{R}$ is a convex function ($C$ a convex set) and $f:M \to \mathbf{R}$ a linear form such that $f \leq g$ on $M \cap C \neq \varnothing$ then $f$ can be extended $\bar{f}:N \to \mathbf{R}$ such that $\bar{f} \leq g$ on $C.$ (This form implies the Hahn-Banach you are thinking of since every norm is convex, you are taking $g$ the norm.) The two statements you are after are connected via Minkowski gauge functions since they are convex and determine what is the algebraic interior of convex sets.